# How to pass parameters to a ElasticSearch plugin in

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch plugin that I want to pass parameters to. These parameters may include passwords.
When testing, I can pass them as `-D` parameter in a docker command.

1. How to better do it in the script `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` ?
2. What options are there to protect sensitive data? It's not very nice to show it on the parameters, since sensitive data would be open in the process signature. This data is used to connect to other services from the plugin to refresh data.

**Update**: This question refers to custom variables, not Elasticsearch's ones.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Elasticsearch's [keystore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/secure-settings.html).

The idea is to set up the keystore with sensitive data in the form of

> FOO=BAR

FOO is the name of the field/variable and BAR the value. You then have to configure the elasticsearch.yml so that it recognizes the path to the keystore. You can then reference these variables like

> elasticsearch.setting.foo: ${FOO}

At runtime, ${FOO} will be resolved to BAR. The keystore is hashed and you can only list the fields, not the values.

**But caution**:

The keystore can only handle elasticsearch-settings, **not** custom ones!

That's just a hint from me, you need to check if you can use the keystore tool in your szenario/plugin.